# Поддержка подсветки и синтаксиса JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ide, jsx

Изучаю библиотеку `React` и использую `Brackets`.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что `IDE` не поддерживает синтаксис JSX и после обновления начал выдавать фантомные ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, изменений в коде как таковых - нет. Это новый созданный проект при помощи create-react-app.

Вопрос касается IDE, и их на самом деле два:

1)Какие инструменты лучше использовать для разработки под реакт, плагины и IDE наиболее расположенные к данной библиотеке?

2)Если используется `Brackets`, какие плагины для работы с react рабочие?На данный момент у меня стоят вот эти плагины, и они не помогают.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Считаю, что этот `ERROR` из-за отсутствия понимания `IDE` JSX'a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте **JetBrains WebStorm** и не морочьте голову с этими редакторами. Поддерживает и `React` и `Vue` и `Angular` и много другое, а также `TypeScript` и `CoffeeScript` если заходите использовать диалект вместо чистого JS. Есть интеграция с `npm`, `git` и поддержка `.ignore` файлов (через плагин). Сколько лет работаю с продуктами JetBrain и не разу не помню чтобы что-то не поддерживалось

Comment: Есть ли бесплатные версии?На данный момент приобрести возможности не имею.

Comment: @Silento можете скачать WebStorm EAP https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP (это типо бета) она бесплатная насколько я помню, но бывают мелкие ошибка (работать не мешают). Если немного погуглите найдете и как обычную версию использовать без проблем. Еще можно обычную версию переустанавливать раз в месяц и можно не покупать (триал 30 дней)

Comment: @Silento, кстати, если назовете файл .jsx наверно и Brackets будет понимать синтаксис правильно

Comment: вы абсолютно правы, я совсем про это не подумал.

Comment: поменял расширение - теперь npm start выдает ошибку, из за расширения не поднимает сервер. Есть идеи?

Comment: `Failed to compile
./src/App.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\converter\converter\src\App.js'
    at Error (native)`

Comment: Ну вы же расширение файла поменял а в ошибке у вас старый файл `App.‌​js` естественно он не найден

Comment: короче я не нашел где это поменять, или как новый создать - все что сделал, сменил формат с js на jsx. Не знаю куда копать

Comment: А чем вы компилируете jsx в js?

Comment: насколько я понимаю - это входит в create react app и там встроен babel

Comment: Ну если там webpack проверьте его настройки, там наверняка указан App.js явно как точка входа

Answer (score 1):

Facebook рекомендует свой [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/) - расширение для [Atom](https://atom.io/).

У меня вполне успешно работает [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/):  (минимальный набор)

- подсветка: [js2-mode](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode), [rjsx-mode](https://github.com/felipeochoa/rjsx-mode) (this mode derives from js2-jsx-mode)
- автокомплит: [ycmd](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd) + [emacs-ycmd](https://github.com/abingham/emacs-ycmd) + [company-ycmd](https://github.com/abingham/emacs-ycmd#company-ycmd) и [tern](http://ternjs.net/doc/manual.html#emacs)-бэкенд для javascript